# Why is this use of union, class and lambda producing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, g++, clang++

I got a very strange bug in my code and managed to reduce it to the following single function.

```
#include "either.hpp"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    using std::string;
    using std::vector;

    auto callback = []()
    {
        auto either = data::either<string,vector<int>>(string("test"));
        return either;
        return data::either<string,vector<int>>(string("test"));
    };
    callback();
}
```

When run, this program generate a segmentation fault on `std::string`'s destructor.
But if we remove the second `return` statement, it work perfectly.

Now, the `data::either` class is using a union with two members, and the lambda's return statement will cause the destruction of the stack-allcated variable.

Is there a problem with my use of those features, is it undefined behaviour for a reason I don't know, or is it simply a compiler bug?

Here is the `either` class:

```
#ifndef EITHER_HPP
#define EITHER_HPP

#include <cassert>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

// Model the haskel Data.Either data type.
// http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Either.html

namespace data
{
    template<class Left, class Right>
    class either
    {
        static_assert(
            !std::is_same<
                typename std::remove_cv<Left>::type,
                typename std::remove_cv<Right>::type
            >::value,
            "data::either<A,B>: type A and B must be different.");

        bool m_is_right;
        union
        {
            Left m_left;
            Right m_right;
        };


    public:
        explicit either(Left l)
            : m_is_right(false)
            , m_left(std::move(l))
        {
        }

        explicit either(Right r)
            : m_is_right(true)
            , m_right(std::move(r))
        {
        }

        either(either const& other)
            : m_is_right(other.is_right())
        {
            if (other.is_left())
            {
                m_left = other.left();
            }
            else
            {
                m_right = other.right();
            }
        }

        either(either&& other)
            : m_is_right(other.is_right())
        {
            if (other.is_left())
            {
                m_left = std::move(other.left());
            }
            else
            {
                m_right = std::move(other.right());
            }
        }

        ~either()
        {
            if (is_right())
            {
                right().~Right();
            }
            else
            {
                left().~Left();
            }
        }

        either& operator=(either const& other)
        {
            m_is_right = other.is_right();

            if (other.is_left())
            {
                m_left = other.left();
            }
            else
            {
                m_right = other.right();
            }

            return *this;
        }

        either& operator=(either&& other)
        {
            m_is_right = other.is_right();

            if (other.is_left())
            {
                m_left = std::move(other.left());
            }
            else
            {
                m_right = std::move(other.right());
            }

            return *this;
        }

        bool is_left() const
        {
            return !is_right();
        }

        bool is_right() const
        {
            return m_is_right;
        }

        Left& left()
        {
            assert(is_left());
            return m_left;
        }

        Left const& left() const
        {
            assert(is_left());
            return m_left;
        }

        Right& right()
        {
            assert(is_right());
            return m_right;
        }

        Right const& right() const
        {
            assert(is_right());
            return m_right;
        }
    };
}

#endif
```

I tested it with the following compilers:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp && ./a.out 
Segmentation fault
$ clang++ --version
Debian clang version 3.2-11 (tags/RELEASE_32/final) (based on LLVM 3.2)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp && ./a.out 
Segmentation fault
$ g++ --version
g++ (Debian 4.7.3-4) 4.7.3
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: @jxh: as of the 2011 revision of C++, `union`s can store types with constructors. However, it is necessary to take care of the proper initialization, destruction, and assignment manually. In C++03 you can only have PODs in a `union`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I think [class.dtor]/5 even says the dtor of the union should be deleted, as the dtor of `string` (and `vector`) is not trivial.

Comment: @DyP: agreed: the destructor is deleted by default if there is a non-trivial member stored in a `union`. Of course, you can provide a user-define destructor doing the right thing (e.g., nothing because the enclosing class does the appropriate destruction using a suitable descriptor and the `union` is `private`).

Comment: @DietmarKühl: Thanks, I'll stick with placement `new` if I want such a `union`. C++ 11 is really like an entirely different language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems in your copy constructor you assume that `m_left` or `m_right` are initialized in a way suitable to assign a `std::vector<int>` or a `std::string`. The member is, however, most likely not initialized at all to be suitable for the class: it is zero-initialized as far as I know. I haven't used C++11 unions enough but I think you need to use

```
new(&this->m_left) Left(other.m_left);
```

and likewise for `m_right`. In the move-constructor you, obviously, need to also insert `std::move()`.

Note that your copy assignment is also likely to be severely flawed: it assumes that left hand side of the assignment has the same type as the right hand side. If the stored types differ, the assignment does **not** work! If the stored types differ, you need to destroy the left hand side's content and construct a copy of the right hand side into it. Off-hand, I'd think I would use the copy&swap approach leveraging the existing copy constructor and the destructor to create a strong exception safe assignment (if swapping the respective current element is non-throwing).

Comment: I think [class.base.init]/8 says that *no* initialization is performed for anonymous union data members. However, it seems as you can designate a member of the anonymous union in the mem-initializer-list of the surrounding class.

Comment: Ok, I understand why it should fail and what I should do, but I still don't understand why the problem does not appear if there is only the first `return` statement. It looks like it should always fail...